# Simple Java Encryption/Decryption - inputFileName doesn't exist

Tags: java, testing, encryption, java-io

This code adds the number 100 after each character.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class FileEncryptionAndDecryption {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws IOException {
        String inputFileName = "DemoFile";
        String encryptedFile = "Encrypted File";
        String decryptedFile = "Decrypted File";
        encryptFile(inputFileName, encryptedFile);
        FileDecryption.decryptFile(encryptedFile, decryptedFile);
    }
    public static void encryptFile(String inputFileName,
        String encryptedFile)
    throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        File file1 = new File(inputFileName);

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file1);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(encryptedFile);
        int[] encrypt = {
            100
        };

        DataOutputStream outputFile =
            new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Encrypt.dat"));

        for (int i = 0; i < encrypt.length; i++)
            fos.write(encrypt[i] + 100);

        System.out.println("Encryption done.");

        outputFile.close();
    }
}

class FileDecryption {
    public static void decryptFile(String inputFileName,
        String encryptedFile)
    throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        File file1 = new File(inputFileName);

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file1);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(encryptedFile);
        int[] decrypt = {
            0
        };

        DataInputStream inputFile =
            new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("Encrypt.dat"));

        for (int i = 0; i < decrypt.length; i--)
            fos.write(decrypt[i] - 100);

        System.out.println("Decryption done.");

        inputFile.close();


 }
}
```

What do I need to do for the 'Demo file' to exist? What would be a good, simple test code? And where should I put comments? I don't want a bunch of unnecessary comments, though I don't know which comments would be necessary.

Comment: "adds the number 100"? so "abc" --->> "a100b100c100"?  I suppose one comment would be to indicate it only works for integers and not characters.

Comment: Using really descriptive variable and function names along with short functions (5-7 lines) goes a long way in replacing comments. Your naming looks pretty good. The problem with comments is that as soon as the code changes they are usually no longer meaningful and.or correct.

Comment: This should be on code review. That site is about cleaning up code that works (commenting). This site is about solving programming questions.

Comment: @nhouser9 Technically, it doesn't work since the Demo file does not exist.

Comment: I think you'll need to fix the encryptFile() method.  The for loop is doing nothing but a single loop, and basically adding 100+100.  I think you meant to loop thru FileInputStream     fis...character by character.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.

Comment: @EJP: No, this doesn't appear to be a good CR question.  It's not really asking for a review, but for additional things to be added.

Answer (score 0):

To create the DemoFile, just use a text editor and put the text you want to encrypt into it : I put the DemoFile.txt into a sub-folder called ./data/.

./data/DemoFile.txt

```
abc
```

Then just put in the path/filename.ext into the code :

```
    String inputFileName = "./data/DemoFile.txt";
```

Also, the following uses while loops for the FileInputStream objects and reads the files, character by character to do the encryption and decryption, which I think is what you intended.

```
        public static void main ( String[] args ) throws IOException {
            String inputFileName = "./data/DemoFile.txt";
            String encryptedFile = "./data/Encrypted.txt";
            String decryptedFile = "./data/Decrypted.txt";
            encryptFile                 ( inputFileName, encryptedFile );
            FileDecryption.decryptFile  ( encryptedFile, decryptedFile );
        }

        public static void encryptFile ( String inputFileName, String encryptedFile )
            throws IOException,
            FileNotFoundException {
            File file1 = new File ( inputFileName );

            FileInputStream     fis = new FileInputStream   ( file1 );
            FileOutputStream    fos = new FileOutputStream  ( encryptedFile );
            int[] encrypt = { 100 };

            DataOutputStream outputFile = new DataOutputStream ( new FileOutputStream ( encryptedFile ) );

            //for ( int i = 0; i < encrypt.length; i++ ) { 
            int r;
            while ((r = fis.read()) != -1) {
                char ch = (char) r;
                System.out.println ( "Reading   ["+ ch + "]" );
                fos.write ( ch+encrypt[0] );
                System.out.println ( "Encrypted ["+ ch+encrypt[0] + "]" );
            }

            System.out.println("Encryption done.");

            outputFile.close();
        }
    }

    class FileDecryption {
        public static void decryptFile ( String inputFileName, String encryptedFile )
            throws IOException,
            FileNotFoundException {
            File file1 = new File(inputFileName);

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file1);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(encryptedFile);
            int[] decrypt = { 100 };

            DataInputStream inputFile = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(encryptedFile));

            //for ( int i = 0; i < decrypt.length; i-- )
            //    fos.write(decrypt[i] - 100);

            int r;
            while ((r = fis.read()) != -1) {
                char ch = (char) (r-decrypt[0]);
                System.out.println ( "Reading   ["+ ch + "]" );
                fos.write ( ch );
                System.out.println ( "Decrypted ["+ (ch) + "]" );
            }

            System.out.println("Decryption done.");
            inputFile.close();

        }
    }
```

I hope this answers your questions.  The code should help get you to your goal...adym